# Tpl for page having url like product/checkout/%/%

Tags: 7, theming, routes

I have created a page with hook menu with url product/checkout/%/% where % will be userid and product id.
How can I add a page tpl for this url ?

Answer (score 2):

In your page callback, you would have to set `'#theme'` on a renderable array.

You can use an existing theme function, or create your own using [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7).

If creating your own and you prefer to use a `tpl`, you can set the `template` option in `hook_theme` and bypass having to create a theme callback function.